# Does Google Maps API allow for interactive links/paths?

Tags: java, google-maps, path, google-maps-markers

I have a Java-based app that is currently using JXMapViewer to display an OpenStreet map as the backdrop to a bunch of interactive vertices (with lat/long attributes) and edges (the vertices and edges are drawn/interacted with via Piccolo, an open-source zoomable library).  When a vertex or edge is clicked, some static data shows in a popup.  I'd like to see if I can move the whole kid-n-kaboodle to Google Maps.  But I couldn't find whether Google's API supports the above requirement of interactive vertices *AND* edges.

I believe the vertices can simply be Google Markers - and I believe those can be made to display customized text when clicked on.  But what about the edges?  I see some ability to draw "paths" in the static map API, but see no mention of interactivity.

Can someone enlighten me?  If it's possible to do the above, can someone point me to code examples and/or demos that do this?